# Connection Ireport

Tags: connection, ip, ireport

I'm having a hard time trying to make the connection from my ireport with the system. My problem is that the system that I use is integrated, in other words, several of my clients will use the same system and therefore the same report. Here is the problem, the name of the bank and the ip of each client are not going to be the same everytime. So I would like to know how jasper could get the bank ip and the bank name from the system by itself and not by the connection made by ireport? Is there anyway to send these data to ireport by code? If so, how could I do that?

Comment: When you say "I'm having a hard time trying to make the connection from my ireport with the system" by system, do you mean the database with all of your data in it? Are you able to connect to it with iReport at all?

Comment: Lisa please look my code below...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of the data source and connection types provided by iReport:

-JDBC connection.

-JavaBean collection data source.

-XML data source.

-CSV data source.

-Hibernate connection.

-Spring-loaded Hibernate connection.

-Hadoop Hive data source.

-JRDataSourceProvider.

-Custom data source.

-Mondrian OLAP connection.

-XMLA connection.

-EJBQL connection.

-Empty data source.

for your case you need "JavaBean collection data source" to fill the report from your java code, using this two classes : net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource, net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanArrayDataSource

Answer (score 0):

My system communicates through the class `Connection`. Java is possible to `.jasper` communicate with the database through this class?

**My Connection**

**==============**

```
 package newpackage;

import java.sql.Connection;

import java.sql.DriverManager;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import java.util.logging.Level;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**

 *
 * @author User

 */

public class ConnectionJava {

    Connection conn;

    public Connection conectar() {
        try {
            Class.forName(DriverConnectionJava);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(database, username, password);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ConnectionJava.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error login with data base", "ERROR!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ConnectionJava.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error connection data base", "ERROR!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }

        return conn;
    }

    public void desconect() {
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ConnectionJava.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    private String database = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/Java";
    private String username = "root";
    private String password = "root";
    private String DriverConnectionJava = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
}
```

Comment: next time add the code in question block instead in answer block